# Vanishing Group Cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n= ord(G)$ and consider the exact sequence provides group extension $E$ by $0 \to M \to E \to G \to 0$ where $M$ has the $G$-module structure.

This gives rise for building (in canonical way) group cohomologies $H^r(G,M), r \ge 1$.

It's obviously clear that because $n= ord(G)$ the canonical multiplication by $n$ map $H^r(G,M) \xrightarrow{*n} H^r(G,M)$ is a zero map.

My question is why is this equivalently to say that $H^r(G,M)\otimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} =0$?

Here I can't use the trick $1 = n/n$ like by showing that it vannishing by tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: In general if an abelian group is $n$-torsion, then it is stable under the tensor product $- \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Say $A$ is an abelian group. Then the cokernel of the multiplication by $n$ map o $A$ is $A/nA = \mathbb Z/n\otimes A$. If multiplication by $n$ is *zero* then certainly $nA=0$ and so $Z/n\otimes A =A$. So your statements are definitely not equivalent. In fact, multiplication by $n$ is *onto* iff that tensor product is zero.